# Android Studio coding Style

Tags: android, android-studio, settings, project, default

Android studio has an option to apply default prefixes to the class members from Default Settings-> Editor->Code Style ->Code Generation Tab. I added the prefix "ABC" ( just for testing) for all type of members and found that the member variables still holds old prefix 'm';

Example: create a new project with a new login activity and see the all the class members will have prefix 'm' and  not 'ABC'
tried reformatting the code (Clt+Alt +L) but  doesn't report any error or change the prefix to "ABC".
I am not sure how this works. Any help in this regard will be very useful.

Answer (score 0):

Read **[Code Style for Contributors](https://source.android.com/source/code-style)**

> The code styles below are strict rules, not guidelines or
>   recommendations. Contributions to Android that do not adhere to these
>   rules are generally not accepted.

1. Non-public, non-static field names start with **m**.
2. Static field names start with **s**.
3. Other fields start with a **lower case letter**.
4. Public static final fields (constants) are
   **ALL_CAPS_WITH_UNDERSCORES**.

Comment: https://medium.com/google-developer-experts/configuring-android-studio-4aa4f54f1153

Comment: Thanks Amiya for quick reply. I am trying to apply java coding standards. Just want to know how can I ensure that my code will adhere to all the  strict rules?

Comment: @Chandra You can use `Analyze->Inspect Code`

Comment: @Amiya : I just tried adding two fields                                                                       private static final int abc = 100; private int xx = 200 and ran Analyze->Inspect code.

Comment: @Chandra then ??

Comment: @Amiya : I just tried adding two fields
 private static final int abc = 100;
 private int xx = 200 and ran Analyze->Inspect code. 
 but it shows no errors/warning related to coding standards. i.e append 'm'  ,'ALL CAPS' etc. I want to force  Android studio to follow the  rules strictly for my java code.

Comment: No. EditorConfig may be another option. but not sure how to setup it in Android Studio.